# What's the best tool for find text differences between multiple files in folders

Tags: windows, search, replace

I need to compare 2 folders with same files but with code differences inside. Is there a tool to be able to compare multiple files in multiple folders and show me all the differences? Preferably free tools and for windows if possible.

Comment: I like winmerge: http://winmerge.org/

Comment: @paul me too, but it doesn't work for multiple files at once

Comment: yes it does, just choose compare folders instead of compare files

Comment: @paul I'm an idiot :) I never saw that, and I used winmerge for long time...there is also the possibility to include subfolders GREAT!